# Blender unwrapping problem

Tags: blend-files

I had an unwrapped model, so i imported it to blender. But no seams are visible. But model is still unwrapped and unwrapped island are visible in image editor
Image for reference. https://drive.google.com/file/d/132FCa4OlEHIK8n1LIrpiDTE2OwzDSNHQ/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 0):

Seams are something Blender uses internally to let it know where you want to cut. They cannot be exchanged between different programms. In fact internally they don't exist at all and those vertices are actully duplicated, since no vertex can have more than 1 position in UV Space. 
I'm not sure why you would need them though, since your mesh is already unwrapped.